# Gray Background in Chrome Devtools sourcemap view

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have a bundled and minified file and a source map. I added this source map in the chrome dev tools by right clicking in the source and selecting `Add Source Map...`. That seems to work (although I suspect that something is getting mixed up). The original files now appear in the devtools. But now some of the lines have a gray background (e.g. line 17 in the screenshot below). What does this mean?[image: devtools screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The gray background indicates that the source map doesn't include those lines. Sometimes source map generators only supply source mapping for lines that differ or have the potential to differ from the underlying code. In these cases, unmodified lines will have a gray background.

See https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1318 for an example of this.

Also see [What are these grey lines in the Chrome sources panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650951/what-are-these-grey-lines-in-the-chrome-sources-panel) for a similar question.